# How to get the value of a variable from java class to JUnit

Tags: java, random, junit, parameter-passing, getvalue

I am testing the function of my calculator:

//Calculator.java (Pseudo)

parameter 1: int

parameter 2: int

parameter 3: a random number generator

sample: `parameter1 (random parameter 3) parameter2`

Now, I am having problems in assert because of the parameter 3 (random).

I can't input a static value in assert, I need to get the value of random first. Help

Comment: Can you share the code of `Calculator`?

Comment: i have updated my question @Mureinik

Comment: But if you're randomizing the operator inside `calculate`, why do you need the third parameter?

Comment: i need the `operator` value so that I can assert. I don't know what to put in the actual of `assertEquals` i need to compute first.

Comment: I don't understand why so many  downvotes. The question contains a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example. The OP tried something and the problem is clearly stated.

Comment: @davidxxx Maybe the question was downvoted before the edit?

Comment: @Modus Tollens Not even. On the OP profile, in the reputation tab I can see : **19 mins ago downvote  
23 mins ago downvote  
37 mins ago downvote**

Comment: @davidxxx Weird. I don't understand either. Upvoted.

Answer (score 2):

You could provide a getter in the Calculator class to retrieve the operator used but it is a limited approach as you will provide the information in the object state.
Consequently, it will always returned the last operator used.
It is not thread safe and in case of exception thrown in the `calculate()` method, you could have surprises if you don't value it with something that indicates that the last one computation has failed.

As alternative instead of returning an `int`, you could return an object wrapping the result (int) and the operator effectively used.

Note that the unit test has to cover all possibles scenarios for your `calculate()` method.
With the randomness of the used operator, guaranteeing that all scenarios were tested is not straight.
You should either open the API of the tested method to select the operator to use (breaking the randomness to have repeatable tests) or perform as many invocations as required of the tested method in your test methods until all cases be covered.

Answer (score 1):

You are defining your `int operator` inside your `calculate` method. The scope of this variable is only inside this block.

```
public class Calculate {

    public int calculate(int a, int b) {
        int operator = randomise(4);
        switch (operator) {
            case 0:
                return add(num1, num2);
            case 1:
                return multiply(num1, num2);
            case 2:
                return subtract(num1, num2);
            case 3:
                return divide(num1, num2);
            default:
                return 0;
        }
    }

}
```

As davidxx said, you could provide a getter in the Calculator class to retrieve the operator:

```
public class Calculate {

    private int operator;

    public int calculate(int a, int b) {
        operator = randomise(4);
        switch (operator) {
            case 0:
                return add(num1, num2);
            case 1:
                return multiply(num1, num2);
            case 2:
                return subtract(num1, num2);
            case 3:
                return divide(num1, num2);
            default:
                return 0;
        }
    }

    public int getOperator()
    {
        return operator;
    }

}
```

Or use the alternative that he proposed.

Answer (score 0):

For your expected result, you want to know the (random) operator that was used. This means that your test actually aims to tests 2 things at the same time:

- Does the calculator select a random operator?
- Is the result of using that random operator correct?

Which theoretically leads to an infinite number of test cases.

It also seems that you use custom methods: add(num1, num2); multiply(num1, num2); etc. Therefore:

- Make separate tests for each of these methods,
- Make it possible to test the random method selection without checking the result of the operation (like [davidxxx](https://stackoverflow.com/users/270371/davidxxx) said above)

The API: assertEquals(int **expected**, int actual) means the code should be '**expected** =' in stead of 'actual =' and then assertEquals(**expected**, resultCalculate);